# How to document Qt based source code

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

How to document the source code I am writing so that other developers see help instructions when hovering the cursor over - for example - a class name I created in Qt creator.
I want to do something like the help you get when put the cursor over a Qt class or function name.

Answer (score 3):

Doxygen + plugin for QtCreator ( http://dev.kofee.org/projects/qtcreator-doxygen/ )
Just change version in *.pluginspec file to 2.4.1, it you are using latest QtCreator version.
Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Doxygen markup and the Doxygen tool will produce supplemental documentation.  The hover over functionality depends on your development environment.  Visual Studio is compatible with Doxygen markup. http://www.doxygen.nl/